# ¿Hay algunas formas de eliminar todo lo concerniente a github de mi proyecto de visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github, eliminar

Para mí, Github es el más grande dolor de cabeza. Hay innumerables problemas al trabajar dos personas el mismo proyecto.

Quizás haya forma de trabajar eso. Pero yo ya fui vencido por github. Llegó a un punto en que me sale desasociado y ya no me permite hacer absolutamente nada.

Quiero eliminar completamente todo acceso, todo repositorio, todo archivo que tenga que ver con Github

¿Es eso posible?

Comment: Borra la carpeta .git. No sé si es lo que buscas

Comment: "Hay innumerables problemas al trabajar dos personas el mismo proyecto." Pero si es para eso!!!! lo debes estar usando mal.. yo aprenderia a usarlo antes de decir que no sirve...

Comment: Te recomiendo usar dropbox, yo lo usaba antes de que existiera github y francamente me funcionaba de maravilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que buscas deshacerte de GitHub sin perder tu historial local de git.
Para ello usaremos [`remote remove`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emremoveem):

```
git remote remove origin
```

De esa manera tu repositorio local ya no estará asociado con ningún repositorio remoto.

---

Probablemente querrás ir al apartado de extensiones en Visual Studio Code y buscar las extensiones de GitHub que tengas instaladas.
Una vez que hayas localizado la extensión de GitHub haz click en el icono de la rueda de engranaje.
Puedes simplemente deshabilitar la extensión o directamente desinstalarla.

---

Si quieres además revocar todos los accesos de GitHub a tu repositorio basta con eliminar el repositorio.
Abre el repositorio en GitHub.
Haz click en *Settings*.
En la parte de abajo del todo encontrarás en rojo *Danger Zone*.
Si tienes suficientes permisos, puedes clicar en *Delete this repository*.